# How to create a reusable code for passport.authenticate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have multiple controllers and each controller has multiple methods. In each method I authenticate the user and use the user id returned from the authentication to get the data from database. I am trying to create reusable code for authentication since the code is repeated.

In the controller:

```
const authenticate = require('../utils/user-authenticate');

exports.getData = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userId = await authenticate.user(req, res, next);
    console.log(userId);
};
```

And in the authentication I have:

```
exports.user = (req, res, next) => passport.authenticate('jwt', async (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      // Send response using res.status(401);
    } else {
      return result;
    }
})(req, res, next);
```

The `console.log(userId);` prints `undefined` always. This is print before passport finishes. Looks like `async/await` does not work the way I want here.

It works if I use `await authenticate.user(req, res, next).then()` but isn't it possible to assign the result directly to `userId` variable?

If I use `return next('1')`: first time `undefined` but second time it prints 1.

Comment: exports.user returns undefined ... Return is scoped within inner callback - if you want to pass it outside wrap it into a promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrapped into a promise:

```
exports.user = (req, res, next) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', async (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      // reject(error)
      // Send response using res.status(401);
    } else {

      resolve(result);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
})
```

but think about:

```
//app.use or something similar
addMiddleware(authJWT);
// later in the chain
useMiddleware((req, res, next)=>{
   // test auth or end chain
   if(!req.JWT_user) return; 
   req.customField = 'one for the chain'
   // process next middleware
   next()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Estradiaz for the suggestion:

> exports.user returns undefined ... Return is scoped within inner
>   callback - if you want to pass it outside wrap it into a promise

Reusable `passport.authenticate`:

```
exports.user = (req, res) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        passport.authenticate('jwt', null, async (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                email.sendError(res, error, null);
            } else if (result) {
                resolve(result);
            } else {
                return res.status(401).json({errors: responses['1']});
            }
        })(req, res);
    });
};
```

And this is how I use it in my controller, for instance in a function:

```
exports.getData = async (req, res, next) => {
   const userId = await authenticate.user(req, res);
};
```